# Need explanation of syntax and use of search/browse return variables

Tags: python, odoo

This is probably in part a python question, but I still think I need to pull odoo into this question.

Here's my code. I just copied it from another piece, without fully understanding what it would do (well I thought I did...)

```
sale_line_ids = self.pool.get('sale.order.line').search(cr, uid, [('order_id', '=', order_id)], context=context)
print sale_line_ids
print 'that was sale_line_ids'
for sale_line_id in self.pool.get('sale.order.line').browse(cr, uid, sale_line_ids, context=context):
    print sale_line_id
    print 'that was one sale_line_id'
    print sale_line_id.product_id
    print 'that was one the product id'
    product_obj = self.pool.get('product.template').browse(cr, uid, sale_line_id.product_id, context=context)
        print product_obj.name
```

And this is the result, interspersed with my questions:

```
[6]
that was sale_line_ids
```

This is expected, the returned variable is just a python list.

```
sale.order.line(6,) 
that was one sale_line_id
```

Now, what's this? It looks like a function with the second parameter missing. This surely can't be the contents of the `sale_line_id` variable? Now it gets even stranger, because in the code the variable `sale_line_id.product_id` is accessed, which *could* mean `sale.order.line(6,).product_id`, which again prints a similar strange string of text:

```
product.product(2,) 
that was one the product id
```

Ok, I don't get it, but it's similar to the previous outcome. Now after this I get a stack trace, which ends in:

```
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 241, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/p711/odoo-addons/p711/models.py", line 67, in paypal_form_generate_values
    print product_obj.name
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 817, in __get__
    self.determine_value(record)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/fields.py", line 910, in determine_value
    record._prefetch_field(self)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 239, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3211, in _prefetch_field
    result = records.read(list(fnames), load='_classic_write')
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 239, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3156, in read
    self._read_from_database(stored, inherited)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 239, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3279, in _read_from_database
    cr.execute(query_str, [tuple(sub_ids)] + where_params)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 158, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 234, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
  File "/home/odoo/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/extensions.py", line 129, in getquoted
    pobjs = [adapt(o) for o in self._seq]
ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'product.product'
```

Clearly the result of trying to access `product_obj.name`, but now I'm lost, can someone give me some insight into this, and maybe explain how and why to do this right?

Comment: Personally I don't see the logic of printing the **string representation** of an object, when you're actually instructing python to **print the object**, but what do I know...

Comment: I guess I was just missing php print_r().. Even `pprint (vars(your_object))` is not universal enough for me. But nevermind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search gives you list of ids and browse gives you browsable records like  product.product(2,).

Just change 1 line to

```
product_obj = self.pool.get('product.template').browse(cr, uid, sale_line_id.product_id.id, context=context)
```

Because browse method takes ids as an arguments not browsable object.
`sale_line_id.product_id` gives you an object not list of ids, so I just changed to `sale_line_id.product_id.id`

sale_line_id.product_id it gives you browsable object.
Nothing is missing in this `product.product(2,)` actually list, tuple , dictionary can have additional comma after the last element.

You will also get fields of product like this,

```
sale_line_id.product_id.name
```

Comment: You say I can also get what I want using sale_line_id.product_id.name. Does that mean the browse in product.template is superfluous?

Comment: Yes it's not required. because you can easily get all these values by . (membership operator dot) like,
sale_line_id.product_id.list_price. And the main thing is, in product.product model you will get all the fields of product.template, for your reference you can see the definition of product_tmpl_id field in addons/product/product.py.

Comment: Will that also work for assignments, i.e. will just coding `sale_line_id.product_id.name = 'newname'` generate an SQL update query to the database?

Comment: No, you should write like this,
`sale_line_id.product_id.write(cr, uid, {key:value})`, you should call the methods with the object so it will the write method of **product.product** because **product_id** becomes an invoking object.